# How to use ntp time (Network Time Protocol server.) as initial time in calender in flutter?

Tags: flutter

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:ntp/ntp.dart';

import '../widget/colors.dart';

class SelectDateFromCalender {
  String? date;
  SelectDateFromCalender._internal();

  static final SelectDateFromCalender _instance =
      SelectDateFromCalender._internal();

  static SelectDateFromCalender get instance => _instance;

  selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    DateTime? newDate = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: DateTime.now().toUtc(),
      firstDate: DateTime(1900).toUtc(),
      lastDate: DateTime(2040),
      helpText: 'Select Date',
      cancelText: "CANCEL",
      confirmText: "SAVE",
      initialDatePickerMode: DatePickerMode.day,
      selectableDayPredicate: _decideWhichDayToEnable,
      builder: (context, child) {
        return Theme(
          data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
            textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                primary: colorPrimary, // button text color
              ),
            ),
          ),
          child: child!,
        );
      },
    );
    date = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(newDate!);

    // Check it for NTP
    // _checkTime('time.google.com');
    return date;
  }

  bool _decideWhichDayToEnable(DateTime day) {
    if ((day.isAfter(DateTime.now().subtract(const Duration(days: 36500))) &&
        day.isBefore(DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 0))))) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  Future<void> _checkTime(String lookupAddress) async {
    DateTime _myTime;
    DateTime _ntpTime;

    /// Or you could get NTP current (It will call DateTime.now() and add NTP offset to it)
    _myTime = DateTime.now().toUtc();

    /// Or get NTP offset (in milliseconds) and add it yourself
    final int offset = await NTP.getNtpOffset(localTime: _myTime, lookUpAddress: lookupAddress);

    _ntpTime = _myTime.add(Duration(milliseconds: offset));

    print('\n==== $lookupAddress ====');
    print('My time: $_myTime');
    print('NTP time: $_ntpTime');
    print('Difference: ${_myTime.difference(_ntpTime).inMilliseconds}ms');

    return;
  }

}
```

So, above is my common class to get date from calender. But I want to use NTP time as initial date. So If user change date from device it won't be changein calender. It shows according to UTC time.

Below is ntp plugin,

[ntp plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/ntp/example)

NTP plugin is used for Fetch accurate time or current DateTime object from (NTP) Network Time Protocol server.

Comment: I don't understand your goal.  Are you convinced that people are setting the time in their device wrong for some reason?  If the device is online, it's almost certainly automatically set to the proper time all on its own.  No need for you to run an ntp query adjacent to that.

Comment: No, How It will set automatically proper time. We have to restrict that by giving NTP time.

Comment: If you want to test then do simply one thing. get current time of device and also print ntp time of device and change the device date and time. and then check the difference

Comment: For example, ios is running an ntp client connecting to time.apple.com internally.  Your phone time is *always* self correcting if there's any kind of network available.

Comment: Yes. What about android phones

Comment: First google hit: "By default in Android 12 or higher, the framework prioritizes NTP as the time source over NITZ because NTP is more accurate and reliable than NITZ. In situations where NTP isn't available, the framework falls back on NITZ. This is a reversal of the default priority from earlier versions of the platform"

Answer (score 1):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:ntp/ntp.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import '../widget/colors.dart';

class SelectDateFromCalender {
  String? date;

  SelectDateFromCalender._internal();
  DateTime initialDate = DateTime.now().toUtc();

  static final SelectDateFromCalender _instance =
      SelectDateFromCalender._internal();

  static SelectDateFromCalender get instance => _instance;

  Future datePickerInit() async {
    initialDate = await NTP.now();
    initialDate = initialDate.toUtc();
    print('NTP startDate: $initialDate');
  }

  selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    DateTime? newDate = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      // initialDate: DateTime.now().toUtc(),
      initialDate: initialDate,
      firstDate: DateTime(1900).toUtc(),
      lastDate: DateTime(2040),
      helpText: 'Select Date',
      cancelText: "CANCEL",
      confirmText: "SAVE",
      initialDatePickerMode: DatePickerMode.day,
      currentDate: initialDate,
      selectableDayPredicate: _decideWhichDayToEnable,
      builder: (context, child) {
        return Theme(
          data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
            textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                primary: colorPrimary, // button text color
              ),
            ),
          ),
          child: child!,
        );
      },
    );

    if (newDate != null) {
      date = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(newDate);
    }

    return date;
  }

  bool _decideWhichDayToEnable(DateTime day) {
    if ((day.isAfter(initialDate.subtract(const Duration(days: 36500))) &&
        day.isBefore(initialDate.add(const Duration(days: 0))))) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Just initialize initial date DateTime.now().toUtc() and then make init method to get initial date in NTP time.